# Macro checking for a date => if true copy line to 2nd sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that copies a line from a table into another table if it fits into the date conditions you give through two date-boxes.

I am struggling with the part where I would need to mix a "For i" If function.
It doesn't seem to work but I can't figure out how to build the macro otherwise.

I get the error:

> "next without for"

when I try to start it.

edit1: I added the missing "End If" - line
When I use "End If" after the first If cycle it tells me "Compilation error - End if used without If Block"
When I use it only after the second if-cycle I get "runtime error 9 - index out of valid range"

I have never needed to use "End If" before.

I added "Sheets("TestArray").Select" to the second If Cycle so it jumps back to the original worksheet but that didn't fix the runtime error.

```
Public Sub ContractDate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ContractNumber(1 To 100) As String
Dim ContractStatus(1 To 100) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ContractDate(1 To 100) As Date
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Array")
Range("G3:G103").ClearContents

For i = 1 To 100
    ContractNumber(i) = sh.Range("F3").Offset(i).Value
Next i

For i = 1 To 100
    ContractDate(i) = sh.Range("B3").Offset(i).Value
Next i

For i = LBound(ContractDate) To UBound(ContractDate)
    If ContractDate(i) > DTPicker21.Value And ContractDate(i) < DTPicker22.Value Then sh.Range("F3").Offset(i) = "YES"
'End If
Next i

For i = LBound(ContractDate) To UBound(ContractDate)
    If sh.Range("F3").Offset(i).Value = "YES" Then
        Sheets("Test Array").Range("A3:E3").Offset(i).Copy
        Sheets("ResultArray").Select
        Range("A3:E3").Offset(i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("TestArray").Select
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `End If` in last `For i` loop.

Comment: Try to ident your code, you’ll notice what’s missing. If you search for Rubberduck vba it has an indent feature

Comment: `End if` is actually missing in the second to last loop as well

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the end if before the last next i

Comment: Thanks! I run into a runtime error if I use "End If" sadly

Comment: Think that the offset you are using during your loop inside your if statement is greater than3